# Webview ignores link with target='_blank'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I'am creating a Android App using Xamarin and I have a webview that loads a page.

The problem is that links on that page that har target='_blank' don't work.
When I click the links nothing happens.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

axml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/webview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Oncreate method

```
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        view.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        view.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        view.LoadUrl("http://itsupport.rn.dk");
```

Comment: Do you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031620/android-webview-ignoring-target-blank-when-added-webviewclient

Comment: Yes I have seen it.. my problem is that shouldOverrideUrlLoading newer is called on link with target=_blank

Comment: Any update? Same problem for me